# Finding app by package name after pressRecentApps() and clicking on it

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm background my app using `pressHome()`, then attempting to foreground it with:

```
uiDevice.pressRecentApps();

String packageName = "my.package.name";

uiDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(packageName)), 60000L);

UiObject myApp = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().packageName(packageName));

myApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

But its giving me a `UiObjectNotFoundException`

Am I doing something wrong?